# Problem with Apple ID while installing Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, install, apple-id

I have been having problems installing Mountain Lion for a while now. First, it was with my Apple ID, which I created myself, and during the installation process, I got an error saying that my Apple ID has not been reviewed in the Apple Store.

I also used my elder brother's, and now it say the Apple ID has not purchased Mountain Lion in the Mac App Store.

So, what's going on?

Comment: Have you already purchased the upgrade or does your Mac come with. Mountain lion? Given the slim details you provide, perhaps some free support from apple will help you narrow down whatever is hanging you up? http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/

Answer (score 1):

Any Mac that could run Mountain Lion (10.8) is also capable of running Mavericks (10.9), which is a free download.  If you don't have a reason to stick with Mountain Lion, downloading a new copy of Mavericks with either of your ID's would be the simplest solution.

Comment: I totally agree with the sentiment to go for the latest OS, however wouldn't the asker still have problems with the Apple ID needing to be validated for use in the store for any download whatsoever? OS X install is no different than any purchase and this seems to be more about troubleshooting the store issue and not about installing an OS.

Comment: It seemed like the OP had access to one Apple ID which could download software; but, not his own Apple ID which was necessary to get the old previously-purchased Mountain Lion.  Signing in with this other account (his brother's), and downloading the free Mavericks installer is a reasonable alternative. As you correctly pointed out, it does nothing to alleviate the outstanding Apple ID issues which will occur the next time a purchase or download is attempted.

Answer (score 1):

Many Macs are not compatible with Mavericks, which is Apple's latest operating system for Macs. Here a support article with the system requirements for Mavericks: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5842

Now let's get back to the Apple ID issue.

What this issue is mainly telling you is that that Apple ID you used doesn't have Mountain Lion in your purchases. If you actually did use your brother's Apple ID there shouldn't be any problem. You can contact AppleCare (if your Mac is still covered under the warranty, if not there may be a charge) to talk about this and they will give you many solutions. I provided some solutions. To chat with an Apple Express Lane Specialist, go to http://www.expresslane.apple.com (again, it is complimentary if your Mac is currently under warranty).

Apple's number is : (1-800-MY-APPLE)

www.apple.com/support/contact

If you erased your hard drive, you should never erase the Mac OS X Base System since that has your installation information. There is maybe a way to reset that information but when you are booted onto OS X Utilities there is no finder application installed, it's nearly impossible. Like I said, try calling APPLE.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into Internet Recovery Mode using COMMAND+R on your keyboard when you are at the boot screen of your mac, as soon as your Mac turns on, boots up, hit COMMAND+R on your Apple Keyboard.

From there, install the Mavericks Installer and Run Install OS X.

For more detailed information on Internet Recovery Mode click [here.](http://www.macworld.com/article/1167870/hands_on_with_mountain_lions_os_x_recovery_and_internet_recovery.html)

[image]